# C++ lib import works except for two constructors

Tags: c++, qt, dll, dllimport

I'm writing a pogram with a third party dll (dynamixel_sdk). I have implemented it in visual studio, which works fine. Right now I'm trying to port the code to Qt to wrap a gui around it.

The include of the dll works fine. It shows and autocompletes me any function and object I write and compiles my code without any problems, but when I try to construct two essential Obejects I get this error:

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: Fehler: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class dynamixel::PacketHandler * __cdecl dynamixel::PacketHandler::getPacketHandler(float)" (__imp_?getPacketHandler@PacketHandler@dynamixel@@SAPEAV12@M@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)

mainwindow.obj:-1: Fehler: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class dynamixel::PortHandler * __cdecl dynamixel::PortHandler::getPortHandler(char const *)" (__imp_?getPortHandler@PortHandler@dynamixel@@SAPEAV12@PEBD@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
```

Afte quite a lot of Google grinding the essence was I have imported it wrong or I made a mistake writing the dll. There can't really be a problem with the dll as far as I can tell, because it works with visual studio.
So far I tried different declereations : as member variable, in the main function and as variable in a member function but nothing seems to work. I also tried to include all headers of the dll seperatly.

I just started using qt with this project, so I can't really tell if there could be a problem with the way Qt includes the dll.

Header (pointer declarations at the bottom):

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "qcustomplot.h"
#include "include/dynamixel_sdk.h"



    /****************************************/
    /*      MEMBER VARIABLE DECLARATION     */
    /****************************************/

    dynamixel::PortHandler   *portHandler;
    dynamixel::PacketHandler *packetHandler;

    QPlainTextEdit *console;

};


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Functioncall:

```
using namespace dynamixel;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setupGUI();
    console= ui->console;

    portHandler   = PortHandler::getPortHandler("COM0");
    packetHandler = PacketHandler::getPacketHandler(PROTOCOL_VERSION);

    portHandler->setBaudRate(BAUDRATE);
}
```

lib import in .pro file:

```
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    qcustomplot.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    qcustomplot.h \
    include/dynamixel_sdk.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/import/ -ldxl_x86_cpp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/import
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/import
```

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Please show the code you used for constructing the classes.

Comment: I just have to call this functions to get a pointer on them.

`portHandler   = PortHandler::getPortHandler("COM0");`

`packetHandler = acketHandler::getPacketHandler(PROTOCOL_VERSION);`

Comment: I think you need to link to an import library for dynamixel_sdk.  Not sure why you posted so much unrelated code however.

Comment: The lib is imported via the .pro file. I added the code snippet to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the Problem: It apperas to have been a problem with the Qt build. It was enough to delete the build directory in my Qt project and rerun qmake.

Answer (score 1):

You have received an error - `Unresolved External Symbol`.

This error often means that some function has a declaration, but not a definition.

Example:

```
// A.hpp
class A
{
public:
  void myFunc(); // Function declaration
};

// A.cpp

// Function definition
void A::myFunc()
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Those functions are defined in the third party dll. I'm just using them. In my VisualStudio project I were just using them like that too.

Comment: Any faulty imports?

Comment: No, I imported the dll with the Qt import function, which sets the include commands for the lib in the .pro file. The dll ist in my working directory and the header is included too. I ported my functions first and compiled them to check if the linking was working, which it does. After that I declared the pointer for the objects and called the construction functions. Thats were the error first appeard.